# In crystal report how to merge column cell for certain rows

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I have one table with 3 columns description, length and width. when I have normal data like description and length and width so it's ok but when I have description and only value in that case i want merge length and width cells. but it's not for all some time it happens. Can you please tell how can i draw this type of crystal report.[image]

please let me know how can i merge cells like this cos this is not fix when it will come.

Comment: if you have two columns and some times there is only value then what will be status of second column? null or any value? how do you know that there is only one value for both the columns

Comment: my main concern is to represent the data like this. This is my need.